# How to check if iis is mvc ready?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am trying to run an mvc3 web app hosted in iis. But I am not able to navigate to the desired page(s). I would like to eliminate the possibility that it is because IIS is not mvc ready. The mvc3 project builds fine in visual studio 2010

Comment: what does MVC ready mean?  You mean if the appropriate .NET FW version is installed?

Comment: Meaning it is ready to accept request for pages in a mvc app. For eg. 
http://localhost/test/Admin/Settings doesnt mean there is such a physical folder.

Comment: that has more to do with the .config of the app and the HttpModules...